# Android - XML Syntax For Strings

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

In my XML values strings code, I have a string with some text that I want to have only a few of the words in color. I also want to have a new line for some of the text.

I can do things like: < b> my bold text < /b> and that works (leading space added for this post).

I try to tag the text with color but no color shows up and there are no errors.

```
name="dogs"
    >Red Dog, <color foreground="#FFFF0000"> Sammy</color></string>
```

I also try adding a new line - I've tried things like:
< LF> some text, space at beginning only for this post < /LF>
< CR> this didn't work either < /CR>
< p> some text, space at beginning only for this post < p>

But, no new paragraph / new line, carriage rtn happens.

What am I doing wrong? Or, more correctly put, **How do I accomplish this?**
Thanks

Comment: Could you update your post to include the relevant Java code where this string resource is used? Are you using the fromHTML() function?

Comment: The string is not being called from java code. The layout xml has a TextView and the string is being called from that TextView's 'Text' property.  The string is correctly called, the only thing is no colors or newline.  Other formats, such as bold, italic work.

Comment: Ahh, I see. You won't like my answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), the three supported HTML tags for values in the strings.xml are (without fromHTML()):

```
<b>
<i>
<u>
```

As for a new line, you could try a bare `\n`. I remember at least one folk reporting it worked.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I discovered, too.  Darn.  Too bad it doesn't generate an error so it would be obvious.  However, the \n did work!  Which surprises me.  I think I'll try out some of the other format things used in pure code.  Thanks again!

Comment: You need to put this int @strings.xml in order for this to work.